# How to store the first N rows of the current record as an array vector?

Tags: sql, arrays, dolphindb

I defined a table as follows:

```
syms = "A"
datetimes = 2021.01.01..2022.01.01
n = 200
t = table(take(datetimes,n) as trade_time, take(syms,n) as sym,take(500+rand(10.0,n), n) as price)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following script:

```
syms = "A"
datetimes = 2021.01.01..2022.01.01
n = 200
t = table(take(datetimes,n) as trade_time, take(syms,n) as sym,take(500+rand(10.0,n), n) as price)

dayNum = 3
tbName = "t"

def getLastNDay(tbName, dayNum){
        colName = "price"
        scripts = "update " + tbName + " set lastNPrice = fixedLengthArrayVector("
        for(n in 1..(dayNum-1)){
                scripts = scripts + "move(" + colName + "," + n + "),"
        }
        scripts = scripts +"move(" + colName + "," + dayNum + "))"
        print(scripts)
        runScript(scripts)
}
getLastNDay(tbName, dayNum)
```

Output:

[image]